# A comment is unneeded and arguably unfriendly - how to flag it?

Tags: discussion, comment-flags, welcoming

I came across this comment today on a (now well-answered) front-end web development question - specifically about [how to automatically number headings with JavaScript or CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51734084/1709587):

> As a hint: Using js you could use loops...

The primary problem with the comment was that it's completely useless, for a few reasons:

- It's obsolete now that there are answers posted.
- The approach it's hinting at is probably not the best one to use, since as the accepted answer notes the problem can be solved more cleanly with CSS counters (neat! I'd never heard of them!) and those apparently [have support going back to IE8](https://caniuse.com/#search=counters).
- Even if you were going to use a JS approach, "use loops" is pretty useless advice, since out of all the parts of JS that the asker would need to use they're the one the asker is most likely to know. It's far more likely that thing that would hold them back from being able to roll their own solution in JS would be not knowing about some of the needed DOM manipulation functions and properties, or just not being able to envisage the overall logic of a solution despite knowing about each of the individual components. If the asker (or a future reader) is genuinely not at the level that they're comfortable using loops (and there's no reason to think this), then even with the advice to "use loops" they're still not going to be able to solve the problem.

All these things mean it warrants a "no longer needed" flag.

But *also*, it's pretty patronising to "hint" at the idea to "use loops" on anything other than a homework problem that seems like it's meant to illustrate how to use loops. The comment serves to communicate the commenter's low opinion of the asker's competence while simultaneously declining to meaningfully engage with the question or offer any guidance that could plausibly be helpful, and that strikes me as mildly rude. It's the sort of mildly-condescending nonsense that would get a sigh out of me if I were on the receiving end, or perhaps require biting back a aggressive response if I happened to be in an angry mood.

For that reason, the comment is (I think?) also a good fit for the new "unfriendly or unkind" flag.

So which to choose? I went for the latter, but I'm not sure whether I'm doing the right thing; on what basis am I supposed to choose between the two flag reasons?

Comment: "As a hint" could also be interpreted as "Take a look at this, I cba to post an in-depth answer right now". Goes both ways. Just my 2 cents though.

Comment: @Stijn Uh, yes. It's framed like an attempt to help, but really just insinuates that the asker lacks minimal knowledge of not just the language they're using but programming in general, while also declining to offer them any practical advice at all. That seems like a textbook example of what "patronising" is, to me.

Comment: Or maybe the commenter really intended to be helpful and give OP a nudge in the right direction. Don't forget you're using a text medium, there's often multiple ways to interpret something, and you really shouldn't assume the worst from the get-go.

Comment: @Stijn Why are the commenter's intentions relevant to how I should flag?

Comment: @MarkAmery The question is rather basic. I think it is reasonable to assume that that particular asker is very new to programming, or at least to JavaScript.

Comment: Was *"assume good intentions"* recently dropped from the SO policy?

Comment: Why wouldn't the commenter's intentions be relevant to how you should flag?

Comment: @ivarni I haven't made any assumptions about the commenters intentions, so I'm unsure what you're getting at.

Comment: _"It's obsolete now that there are answers posted."_ So just flag it as obsolete. Don't over-analyze this.

Comment: @MarkAmery Calling someone patronising for using the phrase "As a hint" is a pretty clear assumption of intent.

Comment: @Cerbrus *"Why wouldn't the commenter's intentions be relevant to how you should flag?"* - for one thing, because the new CoC, linked in the flag description, explicitly says that intent is irrelevant. But also because it genuinely *is* irrelevant. These flags don't (I presume) have any negative consequences whatsoever for the commenter; they're purely a means for tidying up our public-facing artefacts. The original intent of the commenter doesn't alter what I ultimately want the question page to look like; why would it?

Comment: @MarkAmery: The new CoC only mentions "intent" with: _"No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language."_. There is no _"subtle put-down or unfriendly language"_ here. So the "Intentions are irrelevant" clause doesn't apply.

Comment: I'm quite sure that rude/unfriendly flags on an user's comments have more impact in the long run as 'no longer needed' flags.

Comment: And as @Codeer said, R/A flags piling up in a user's history does draw negative attention from a moderator.

Comment: @Cerbrus *"The new CoC only mentions "intent" with: "No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language.".* - That's the precise section that the flag description links to - so it seems to me that this is exactly the circumstance in which the clause *does* apply.

Comment: @MarkAmery: That's where the flag description ___you chose___ links to, yes. That association only exists because ___you___ chose the wrong flag.

Comment: @Cerbrus *"R/A flags piling up in a user's history does draw negative attention from a moderator"* ... but these aren't R/A flags. I would've thought that the entire point of creating a new flag class was to allow indicating that a comment has a problematic tone *without* summoning down consequences for the commenter. If not, why keep the "abuse" and "unfriendly" options as distinct classes at all?

Comment: @MarkAmery: That's another discussion.

Comment: @Cerbrus *"That association only exists because you chose the wrong flag"* - that seems clearly circular. As I understand it, you're now arguing that because of the OP's lack of intent, the flag (whose description states that intent is irrelevant) doesn't apply, and so I can't argue from the lack of intent clause. That doesn't make sense, and would effectively nullify the lack of intent clause completely.

Comment: @MarkAmery: You categorize the comment as _"Unacceptable Behavior"_, the only category where "intent" is mentioned. That categorization is incorrect. What I'm saying is that _"intent is irrelevant"_ doesn't apply because it's not a _"subtle put-down or unfriendly language"_. The flag you chose is incorrect, the the "intent clause" under that flag __does not apply__ to the comment.

Answer (score 32):

If the OP *does* lack the minimal understanding of programming in general, a hint to look at loops can be ***very*** helpful.

Imagine for a second, if you don't know loops exist in programming, the world that opens up to you when someone tells you:

> *As a hint: Using js you could use loops...*

If you then google *"js loops"*, you'd be set!

So, I disagree on both counts: The comment isn't unneeded, and it's not unfriendly.

> *"You're an idiot, you didn't use loops!"*

That's unfriendly.

Comment: When you say it's neither unneeded nor unfriendly, are you genuinely arguing for keeping the comment around? I can see arguing against labelling it "unfriendly", but keeping it seems nuts. You could just as well justify keeping a permanent "Hey! If you're new to programming, I recommend [my favourite programming book]" comment on every new user's question with the reasoning here.

Comment: @MarkAmery: _"but keeping it seems nuts"_ Please don't use such strong language to disagree with me. You're also bringing in _completely_ unrelated examples now. Yes, I think the comment _is_ helpful. If another user has a similar problem, and is made aware of the existence of the awesomeness that is "loops", yay for the comment!

Comment: I would like to add that it can _become unneeded_. For example when it's used in an answer.

Comment: You have 2 quotes with salutations: positive and negative.  I wish you'd add a third that's just "Use loops".  I'm wondering if that would truly be perceived as neutral or if it would be condemned as unwelcoming.

Answer (score 9):

You are actually answering your own question already in the title:

> A comment is unneeded and **arguably** unfriendly

It already states that you are uncertain about the matter *if* the comment is actually unfriendly. You are judging the comment definitely as unneeded, so just flag it as that.

In my opinion, it is the best to only use the rude/abusive/unfriendly flag when *you* are a 100% convinced of the rude/unfriendly behavior. This is mainly because **both** the  rude/abusive *and* unfriendly flags can trigger moderation involvement if multiple helpful ones are raised on an user (see [Samuel Liew's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372262/9420984)). These flags are heavier to use as the 'no longer needed flag'.

I do realize that different people have different interpretations, hence it is *your* opinion here that counts.

From my own point of view: if I am definitely sure about a comment being unneeded, but not certain about it being unfriendly (even if it might suggest it), I'd use the 'No longer needed' flag.

Comment: *"it is the best to only use the rude/abusive/unfriendly flag when you are a 100% convinced of the rude/unfriendly behaviour."* - why? Given a comment that you think ought to be deleted for some reason anyway, why should I be more restrained about picking one reason than another?

Comment: Because that's how flagging works on SO. You only chose the flag you're 100% sure that applies.

Comment: Because rude/abusive/unfriendly flags can count as a penalty against an user if a lot of them are raised.

Comment: @Codeer I doubt that's true since I can't see any reason that we'd have two different flag classes if it were the case. But I've [asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372207/1709587), to find out for sure.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm not even sure what it means to be "100% sure" that a subjective definition about the tone of something applies. I'm 100% sure that *I* find the tone unfriendly and unkind. Sure, it's pretty obvious that some other people would dissent - but different standards of politeness across the site are diverse enough that *any* comment that someone thinks is "unfriendly or unkind", a large number of other users will disagree about. What standard do you propose applying, besides just never using the flag at all?

Comment: I am. I can promise you there have been plenty of comments that I could be 100% sure of of my flag getting validated.

Comment: @MarkAmery: You're talking "debatable" comments. If the "rudeness" is "debatable", don't flag it. And please stop putting words in my mouth. I'm not saying the flag can never be used. Just don't use it for petty, possibly slightly unfriendly if taken the completely wrong way, comments.

Comment: @MarkAmery If you are a 100% sure the tone of a comment is unkind, flag it as such. In the wording of this meta question, you clearly *weren't* a 100% sure about it being unfriendly. You were sure about it being unneeded, though.

Comment: @Cerbrus I can't imagine an example of non-"debatable" rudeness that wouldn't warrant a "harassment, bigotry or abuse" flag instead.

Comment: @MarkAmery: That might have to do with you finding the example comment "unfriendly".

Comment: ^ Now, that was rude. But not harassment, bigoted, or abusive.

Comment: @Codeer You haven't really clarified anything. What does it mean to be "100% sure" of the tone of something? You're asking for total certainty about the application of a subjective standard that the community is wildly split over how to interpret (at least based on all the "welcoming" discourse since Jay's blog post). That seems likes an impossible standard.

Comment: @MarkAmery I can be a 100% convinced that something is *intended* as rude / abusive / unfriendly. In that case I use such a flag. If I am convinced that a comment is *definitely*  unneeded but *perhaps* unfriendly, my 'definitely' weighs out the 'perhaps'. Someone calling somebody an 'idiot' is definitely unfriendly to me, for example.

Comment: I agree `100% convinced`, I'm so glad they have the unfriendly flag. It makes it easier to process those comments that are "arguably" rude.

Comment: @MarkAmery the restraint is required for R/A comment flags, as with R/A and spam flags on posts, as they bear further consequences. Helpful R/A comment flags trip auto comment flags alerting mods of patterns of bad behaviour.