# Does the new "unfriendly" flag have negative consequences for flagged users?

Tags: support, comment-flags, welcoming

Multiple commenters at [A comment is unneeded and arguably unfriendly - how to flag it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372201/1709587) seem to be of the view that having several of the new "unfriendly or unkind" flags raised on your comments will cause bad things to happen to you.

This seems surprising to me. I had assumed that the *entire point* of separating out the "abuse" flag category from the "unfriendly" flag category was that accumulating the former would draw moderator attention to the user while accumulating the latter would be without consequence.

What's actually the case? And if "unfriendly" flags draw moderator attention to the user just like "abuse" flags do, then what's the point in having them as separate flag types at all?

Comment: Sigh, at least I can still downvote without fear of unfriendliness, for now...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I think the take away here is that flagging a comment as "unfriendly" is not welcoming.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Based on [Yvette's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313758) posted on MSE, and confirmation via [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313754/updated-comment-flagging-supporting-the-new-code-of-conduct/313758#comment1027938_313758) by Nathaniel:

> I just received a "CommentTooManyDeletedRudeNotConstructiveAuto" autoflag after flagging a comment as "unfriendly" – so it seems like it has been mapped to the "Not Constructive" option. – [Nathaniel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/300411/nathaniel)

It seems that both "harassment, bigotry, or abuse" and "unfriendly or unkind" both count towards the same "CommentTooManyDeletedRudeNotConstructiveAuto" flag that moderators get when a user's comments get too many of either type of comment flag within a certain period.

Comment: Yep. For the time being they both get rolled into one. We'll be looking over this and seeing if it's kicking up too much noise, if it needs to be addressed... but we don't want to make any assumptions at this point. It's probably most likely to impact SO more than any other site. Also worth remembering that the current flag volume may not be the sustained volume.

Answer (score 7):

Multiple *"harassment, bigotry, or abuse."* flags result in automatic deletion of the comment.

As far as I know, that's not the case for the "unfriendly" flag.

---

That said, a long list of these flags on a user's profile will surely raise a moderator's eyebrow. If the only reason to flag the comment is that it's no longer needed, and you think it might possibly be somewhat unfriendly, just flag as *"no longer needed"*.

Comment: when a user *previously* got a couple of Rude/Abusive comment flags (now renamed to "harassment, bigotry, or abuse") within a certain period of time, mods get an auto "too many R/A comments flag" on the user (draw moderator attention). Mark is asking if this is the same case for the new unfriendly flag - not that we mods know of yet, as it's still too early to tell

Comment: (Might as well get used to the new names as soon as possible @SamuelLiew)

Comment: Also to make a bit of a point and because of all the confusement around the new flags. Even the mods don't seem to know how they exactly work :(

Comment: @AndréKool there, fixed ;)