# How does the new "unfriendly" flag differ from the old "not constructive" flag?

Tags: discussion, unfriendly-or-unkind

Related: [Is a comment telling someone not to answer constructive?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348633/is-a-comment-telling-someone-not-to-answer-constructive)

The "unfriendly" tag seems to have a similar role to the older "not constructive" reason. In fact, [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372262/4032703) even seems to imply that it behaves similarly to the old "not constructive" reason "internally."

Will a lot of the things that used to be considered "not constructive" now be considered unfriendly? For example, in his answer to the linked post, [Brad Larson♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) argues that comments telling people not to answer off-topic questions are not constructive and should be flagged accordingly. That being said, will they now be treated as unfriendly instead?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The big issue with "not constructive" was... Folks used it for everything. Rude comments, unfriendly comments, jokes, non sequiturs, blather, noise ...

It didn't *mean* anything.

The hope is, this new flag will be limited to a subset of that. The ... Unfriendly subset.

Comment: Should these comments be flagged as unfriendly?

Comment: Probably? Depends on the comment.

Comment: I could be extremely polite in a comment that is completely off topic.  Or I could be very rude telling someone to very minute details every, single, thing, they did wrong.

Answer (score 10):

"Not constructive" seems closer to "no longer needed", and "unfriendly" more seems like a less severe "rude", although there may be some overlap. At least that's based on the literal meaning of the words (ignoring how people may be using it).

#### Explanation by example:

> This is a horrible question. Have you tried X, Y or Z?

Unfriendly (or rude).

Somewhat constructive.

---

> This is a horrible question.

Unfriendly (or rude).

Not constructive.

Not needed ("no longer needed").

---

> What do you think of XKCD?

Not constructive.

Not needed ("no longer needed").

Not unfriendly.