# If I flag a comment as unfriendly, but the user self-deletes it, does the commenter suffer a negative consequence?

Tags: discussion, flags, unfriendly-or-unkind

I understand that a negative consequence of some kind can befall a commenter who attracts too many Unfriendly flags. From what I have seen from moderator answers here on Meta about it, it is a consequence that moderators cannot change. Thus, I believe some mods are in the habit of rejecting Unfriendly flags, perhaps if the flagger was too sensitive, even if the intent of the flagger was broadly helpful.

I don't know what this negative consequence is; I assume it is a rate-limit or temporary ban applied to new questions.

However, I am not sure what happens in this case:

- A remark is made that has an unfriendly/hostile interpretation
- This comment is flagged as Unfriendly
- Another commenter asks the first commenter to reconsider their remark, given the potential for misinterpretation
- The commenter agrees and self-deletes it

I have one of these in my recent history, and given that the commenter was amenable to feedback, I don't think a negative consequence is appropriate. What happens in this case?

### Related question

[Does the new "unfriendly" flag have negative consequences for flagged users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372207/does-the-new-unfriendly-flag-have-negative-consequences-for-flagged-users)

Comment: Whatever the answer ends up being, I'm split on my opinion of how it should be implemented. On one hand, I prefer that a person re-reading their comment and realizing they were unking and deletes it to not be punished because they're removing the unfriendly content, so it seems like the kind of behavior we would want to encourage. Yet on the other hand, this could easily be abused, as a person could be intentionally unkind, knowing that if they delete the comment after a couple of minutes, that there won't be any repercussions.

Comment: @DavyM Possibly track that separately? i.e. comments flagged as unkind and self deleted tracked independently and could be used as a separate kind of threshold ("this user is being unfriendly and self-deletes, lets review...")

Comment: @DavyM: that's a very good point. However, it may not be a problem in practice, since it's a risky ploy - a moderator might be around and catch it before it is self-deleted.

Comment: @Halfer Good point, especially since (I think) deleted comments are still visible to mods, so if a mod suspects someone is abusing it, they can still trace back the offense and manually issue the ban.

Comment: @DavyM: yes, all deletes are soft deletes here (except security deletes for sensitive information, which have to be done by devs).

Comment: @DavyM that could be solved by removing only half (or some other percentage) of the negative indicators. This would encourage users to delete unkind comments when they realize their error (as half /or more/ negative feedback would be removed with the comment), but does not encourage intentional unkindness followed up by comment removing (as negative feedback would still accumulate, albeit at a slower rate). I don't have any idea if such non-integer counting could be supporeted in SO framework, though.

Comment: @DavyM The difference between a nasty comment that is immediately deleted to hide it and an unkind comment that is deleted after someone points it out is quite obvious, and we can trust moderators to tell the difference and to penalize the former but not the latter ... and note that the former is far *less* likely to be flagged (by anyone other than the moderator) than the latter, so the former is *not* a matter of abusing the ability to delete flagged comments without being penalized.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The flag is marked as helpful and handled by the user who deleted their comment. I don't remember if there are still any auto-flags for "many comments by this user flagged unfriendly or unkind" or somesuch, but there are no direct, material penalties incurred by having a comment flagged and deleted, nor for flagging a comment that eventually gets deleted by its author. Someone in the business of being a nuisance may get a talking-to from us, but it's all manual and up to our discretion.

If the user has learned their lesson, I'd say no further action needs to be taken and they don't need to be monitored or anything like that. You pointed out that a comment was inappropriate; the author conceded and deleted it. The system works.

Comment: Yes, those self-removed comments that were flagged still count toward and trigger the "too many NC/rude comments by this user flagged within the past X days" auto flag

Comment: _If the user has learned their lesson, I'd say no further action needs to be taken_ - that is what I am saying too. Thanks Boltclock.

Comment: If there are no consequences and all these flags are alike, then 1) why do we have different types and 2) why do moderators have to handle them and not users? Doesn't sound like "the system works" to me at all. Is all that the "welcome wagon" boils down to in practice more pointless busy-works for moderators?

Comment: @Lundin: 1) Probably for statistics and to educate users what finite set of reasons they can flag a comment for without lumping them all into a single loaded option 2) Dunno. I would entrust comment flags to a select few users who understand what sorts of comments should be deleted, *when* they should be deleted (there's a reason it's called "no longer needed" and not "not needed", for example), and when somebody may be using flags simply to mean "This comment is wrong" or "I don't like this comment".