# Are users still punished for "unfriendly or unkind" comments left on deleted posts?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, comment-flags

Occasionally I come across very low quality questions (more than 5-7 down-votes) and I see a rude/condescending comment reprimanding the more often than not "new contributor". Typically I'll vote to close the question *and* flag the unnecessary comments as "It's unfriendly or unkind".

When I see that my flag on the comment was marked as helpful, I'd say 90% of the time or more the question was deleted anyways (maybe by the author, maybe by a moderator) - my question is, do these deleted comments still count against the users, or are they excluded because the question was deleted anyway?

Maybe I'm being pedantic, but no matter the question quality I don't think there's any excuse to write these types of comments.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, the "punishment" that exists for users who leave a large number of "unfriendly or unkind" comments still applies when the comments are left on deleted posts.

That's a bit of an overstatement, because there isn't really such a "punishment". But the response mechanism that *does* exist continues to work in the scenario you describe.

Allow me to elaborate: What happens in the scenario you describe is that deletion automatically marks all pending flags on comments as "helpful", similar to what would have happened if a moderator would have manually deleted those individual comments in response to a flag. Then…nothing else happens, unless and until the system detects that a user has a *pattern* of leaving abusive comments, then moderators are notified, allowing us to manually review the comment history and reach out to the user as appropriate.

This is somewhat hand-wavy, as I don't intend to disclose the exact pattern that signals moderators of potential comment abuse. The larger point is that, yes, we'll still find out.

I would like to see this improved so that "harassment, bigotry, or abuse" flags on comments *don't* get automatically cleared when the associated post is deleted. These, if correct, tend to be so bad that they require *immediate* moderator attention. If you see a comment or two that rises to that level, and it looks like the associated post is about to be deleted, please feel free to raise a custom moderator flag on the *post* (i.e., not the comment) and point us to the comments. Make sure to be clear about what you're actually flagging, or you'll confuse us. Unlike flags on comments, custom moderator flags on posts are not automatically cleared when a post is deleted.

Comment: Yes, "punishment" was a poor word choice - I'm aware that a user needs a substantial amount of these types of flags before a moderator reaches out to them. But what if someone flagged a perfectly fine comment and then the question is deleted... that flag would be marked as "helpful"?

Comment: Yes, it would be marked as "helpful". Comment flags have two dispositions: "declined" and "helpful", which are supposed to be mapped to "keep comment" and "delete comment", respectively. When the *entire post* gets deleted, the system considers this as equivalent to deleting the comment(s). @dwirony

Comment: So if I flag a bunch of comments under one of my posts then delete the post, the flags are all marked helpful?

Comment: @TinyGiant, nice way to game the system to be able to moderate users rather then content ;) But I guess this will come back round to you one way or another.

Comment: This seems to suggest that "harassment, bigotry, or abuse" and "unfriendly or unkind" flags are actually different in some way. I had read (or hallucinated?) between the lines of the feedback I got at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372262/1709587 that they were identical in behaviour in every way and should be used interchangeably. Hmm. Maybe worth me posting a separate question when I have the chance about exactly what the differences are and when to use each; the descriptions of both list a broad enough set of behaviours *anything* that meets the definition of one meets the other too.

Comment: @Mark Sam's answer is correct. They currently are both treated the same way as far as the system is concerned for providing us with automatic notifications about a pattern of abusive comments coming from a particular user. I would propose, though, that "harassment, bigotry, and abuse" be treated slightly differently, in that it would *always* provide notification to a moderator to allow us to take immediate action. Everyone uses them as if they're separate categories because, um, they *are* separate categories. Don't try to reverse-engineer the system; use it for the labels on the tin.

Answer (score 12):

To add on [Cody's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384722/6451573), we can also choose to delete the comment (because it's borderline or just no longer needed), but not punish the user for that.

Example: a poor question is asked, and some user posts something like:

> Hello, welcome to SO, SO isn't a coding service, your question is too broad.

Those comments are sometimes flagged as "rude" or "harassment". To me, it sends mixed signals (welcoming the user, then dismissing the question in a curt way). In those cases I tend to:

- dismiss the flag
- delete the comment (or in some rare cases edit it to remove some `!!!` or other stuff which can be seen as unfriendly, only in otherwise *very helpful* comments)

That tends to "punish" the flagger (because the flag was declined), but it's better than punishing the commenter, who in that case tried to help.

Comment: I disagree that "they tried to help" some of the most heinous abuse directed towards me in the past has been done in the most passive-aggressive "polite" way possible. It is completely possible to write in such a way to claim it is "polite" and a complete condescending a$$hat at the same time, they are not mutually exclusive. Your attitude of punishing the person that is objectively doing the right thing instead of the person that is trying to hide their abuse in "polite" language is why I quit flagging stuff and am not participating like I once did, you might want to reconsider your position.

Comment: true, it's left to the moderator appreciation. There are several moderators with different sensibilities, which means that users who play this little borderline game a little too much won't win in the long run. I also noticed that people tend to see snark when people genuinely want to help. Hard to detect snark sometimes, even for a human

Comment: I don't see this example as offensive. Is it super helpfull, no it isn't either. If someone would add "see [ask] for tips on how to write a good question" it would be better.

Comment: "SO isn't a coding service" is borderline, though :)