# Deleting and undeleting a post clears all comment flags

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-flags

So, I recently flagged several comments on a question as "Unfriendly or Unkind." The OP subsequently deleted the question and then undeleted it a few minutes later.

My flags were marked "helpful" when the question was deleted, but when it was undeleted the rude comments were still there. Not only that, I was unable to flag them again, and they presumably disappeared from the mod queues. (Correct me if I'm wrong).

Can this be fixed? Undeleting a post should ideally re-activate any pending flags on it (or its comments), and at a minimum I should be able to re-flag them.

Comment: Related (don't *think* it's a duplicate): "[*Are users still punished for “unfriendly or unkind” comments left on deleted posts?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384721/1364007)".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has been fixed. The following changes are now live:

- Flag auto-resolve when post deleted

  - When a post is deleted (not by a mod), some flags for moderator attention are auto-resolved as `helpful`.
  - Previously flags of type `Other` and `VandalismDeletions` auto-flags were not auto-resolved (so that a mod would still see them)
  - The list of flags auto-resolved (so that they will still be brought to the attention of a mod) now includes `CommentTooManyDeletedRudeNoConstructive` auto-flags, `ModRevisionRedactionApproval` and `Offensive`.
  - `Offensive` flags are only not auto-resolved when the post was deleted by vote
- When a post is undeleted and there were flags that had been auto-resolved on deletion of the post (including comment flags), the resolved state of the flags is cleared and they are returned to their pending state.

---

> An issue is flagged
> Post deleted, flag is gone
> Undelete, flag back

Answer (score 8):

This isn't a fix to the issue per se, but a workaround.

If the post is deleted and undeleted, clearing the flags, raise a moderator flag on the post or one of the comments explaining the circumstance. The moderator can see the auto handled flags on the post and then deal with them.

The other bonus is when there's an accumulation rude or unkind flags are marked as helpful on an author's comments, it will auto raise a moderator flag to manually review that user's behaviour. Most moderators will also investigate the posts where there's been flag activity so they can also deal with comment threads or problematic behaviour.